# How to pattern match list containing float values?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've a list containing float values with 1 decimal point precision e.g. `3_element_list = [4.3, 2.2, 8,9]`. With a function `def check_pattern(list: List[float], pattern: List[float]) -> bool:` I'd like to check if the list matches a predefined pattern `pattern` which reflects which list element should be biggest dependent on the list element count.

W.r.t. `3_element_list` `3` means biggest, `1` means smallest. Means given the pattern `3_element_match_pattern = [2, 1, 3]` the function should return `True`, in case the pattern would be `3_element_mismatch_pattern = [3, 2, 1]` the function should return `False`.

The other way around given a `4_element_pattern=[4, 3, 2, 1]` I'd like to get `True` for `4_element_match_list=[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]` and `False` for other lists like `4_element_mismatch_list=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
three_element_list = [4.3, 2.2, 8.9]
three_element_match_pattern = [2, 1, 3]
three_element_mismatch_pattern = [3, 2, 1]

four_element_match_list=[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]
four_element_mismatch_list=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
four_element_pattern=[4, 3, 2, 1]

six_element_list = [3.222, 3.644, 2.0, 4.756, 4.644, 2.222]
six_element_match_pattern = [3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2]


def check(lst, pattern):
    s = sorted(lst)
    return all(s[v-1] == val for v, val in zip(pattern, lst))

print(check(six_element_list, six_element_match_pattern))

print(check(three_element_list, three_element_match_pattern))
print(check(three_element_list, three_element_mismatch_pattern))
print(check(four_element_match_list, four_element_pattern))
print(check(four_element_mismatch_list, four_element_pattern))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
False
True
False
```

---

EDIT: New version

Comment: I wondered why I get with `print(check(six_element_list, six_element_match_pattern))` , `six_element_list = [3.222, 3.644, 2.0, 4.756, 4.644, 2.222]` and `six_element_match_pattern = [3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2]` the output `False` (should be `True`)?

Comment: @thinwybk The `six_element_list = [3.222, 3.644, 2.0, 4.756, 4.644, 2.222]` has pattern `[3, 6, 1, 2, 5, 4]` not `[3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2]` -> notice the `2.222` is on the last, 6th place

Comment: Probably the question was not stated explicit enough, but isn't `4.756 > 4.644 > 3.644 > 3.222 > 2.222 > 2.0]` corresponding to `6 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1` means `[3, 4, 1, 6, 5, 2]`?

Comment: @thinwybk Yes, I've misunderstood your question - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```py
def check_pattern(values, pattern):
    valuesSorted = sorted(values)
    for idx in range(len(values)):
        print(idx)
        if values[idx] != valuesSorted[pattern[idx] - 1]: return False
    return True
```

should do the trick.

Explanation:

- First we sort the array - so now we have the values in the order from lowest to highest
- This means if there is a `1` in the pattern it means it must be `valuesSorted[0]`, otherwise it would not be the lowest value and the array is not sorted according to the pattern.
- So now we just need to compare if the values in the array are in the correct position - if they're not we can just return false and break out.